# Need to call powershell script from batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a batch file which is in a folder called script. The script folder also contains folder called powershell which has a script called IE-Settings.ps1.

I want to execute the powershell script from the batch file and I am unable to give powershell script path in the command. What I tried is

```
call %windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File "& '%~dp0IESettings\IE-Settings.ps1'"
```

But it doesn't recognize the path

Comment: `%~dp0IESettings\..` or `%~dp0Powershell\..` ?

Answer (score 0):

`call` is for running other batch files in a way that they return to the current batch file after they terminate, and per your question the subdirectory name is `powershell`, not `IESettings`. Also, when using the parameter `-File` you just specify the path to the file.

```
powershell.exe -File "%~dp0powershell\IE-Settings.ps1"
```

The call operator (`&`) is used when running PowerShell code via the `-Command` parameter, e.g.:

```
powershell.exe -Command "& { Write-Host 'foo' }"
```